# Training labels unequal distribution

Tags: python, deep-learning, training-data, data-augmentation

My task is to estimate diastolic blood pressure (DBP) from PPG and ECG data. However the DBP labels are distributed unequally.

I am using Diastolic blood pressure as training labels. The range that I [as shown inn figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xqLg.jpg)am considering is 16mmHg - 276mmHg, however, majority samples lie in the range of 45mmHg - 110mmHg, because of this model is learning this range efficiently, and is not predicting the values outside this range. What can be the solution to this problem?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i8Td.jpg)